# Pure CSS triangle with semi-transparent border. Possible?

Tags: css, webkit, mobile-safari

Is it possible to draw an arrow that has semi-transparent border around it just using css?
[image]

Heres a fiddle of my effort so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/calebo/fBW4u/

CSS:

```css
.ui-overlay {
  padding-bottom: 10px;   
  position: relative;
}
.ui-overlay-content { 
  background: #999;
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px; 
  border: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); 
  background-clip: padding-box; 
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}
.arrow {
  border-color: #999 transparent transparent; 
  border-style: solid; 
  border-width: 10px 10px 0; 
  bottom: 5px; 
  left: 15px; 
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden; 
}
```

Comment: I'm after solution for mobile safari only. Not taking other browsers into consideration.

Comment: related question with a transparent arrow : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23758922/transparent-arrow-triangle

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This still needs some work, but here's the general idea:

Use a pseudo-element, rotate it 45deg and apply the styling to that:

```css
.arrow {
    bottom: -25px; 
    left: 30px; 
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.arrow:after {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    background: red;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    position: absolute;
    top: -19px;
    left: 3px;
    background: #999;
    border: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yZ3vB/

---

The problem with this is that the borders overlap, making it darker by the edges.

This could probably be remedied by adding another element though.

**Update:** Yes! Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/sJFTT/

---

**Update 2:** You don't even need that additional element. You can use the pseudo element from the main box:

```css
.ui-overlay-content:after {
    content: ' ';
    border-width: 13px;
    border-color: #999 transparent transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: 30px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6v9nV/

---

**Update 3:** Actually, you can do all this *with just a single element* and no transform, by using both pseudo-elements - the `before` and the `after`:

```css
.speech-bubble {
    background: #999;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #444 0%,#999 100%);
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    padding: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
.speech-bubble:before{
    content: ' ';
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) transparent transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 17px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -39px;
    left: 16px;
}
.speech-bubble:after{
    content: ' ';
    border-color: #999 transparent transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 13px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -26px;
    left: 20px;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/95vvr/

---

**P.S.** Don't forget the vendor prefixes in production!

Comment: Thanks for that, do you know if it's possible to have the border radius applied to '.ui-overlay-content' as well, not just the semi-transparent border.

Comment: anything simple that could be added to https://github.com/quantumjs/smart-terminal, currently the borders can not use 'border-colour:transparent'

Answer (score -2):

You need notch image and place that image absolutely at bottom right corner.[image]

Comment: The question is to implement it using only CSS and not images.

Comment: No we cannot implement it using CSS.

Comment: You should have a look at the answers other users have provided.

Comment: sorry, i only need to support mobile safari.