# create tag shape with css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a tag shape with the css only so that it looks like:

[image]

I'm trying following but unable to use the border for the triangle area.

HTML:

```
<a href="#">Test</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
a{
    float: left;
    height: 35px;
    position:relative;  
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-right: none; 
    width: 100px;
} 

a:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    right: -18px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: white white white red;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 19px 0 18px 18px; 
}
```

**JSFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/Sac3m/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875968/pure-css-triangle-with-semi-transparent-border-possible - use the final approach in the accepted answer. You need to use both `::before` and `::after` to get the border on your arrow.

Comment: @CherryFlavourPez awesome, I had no idea that answer existed and the first attempt there looks eerily similar to what I did in mine :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could rotate a square instead, although i doubt the results will be great cross-browser

Modified code:

```css
a {
  float: left;
  height: 35px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-right: none;
  width: 100px;
}

a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  right: -13px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-left: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<a></a>
```

(Latest IE, Firefox and Chrome seems OK with it)

---

### Update

If you need IE8 support, you could try to put a white triangle on top of the (original) red triangle:

```css
a {
  float: left;
  height: 36px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-right: none;
  width: 100px;
}

a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  right: -18px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: white white white red;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 19px 0 19px 19px;
}

a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -17px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 18px 0 18px 18px;
}
```

```html
<a></a>
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks nice but unfortunately it doesn't support IE8 which I need.

Comment: Thanks. I have accepted the answer although it doesn't work in Opera.

Comment: @user966582 Cheers. Just tested, and the first version works in Opera. You could supply the second solution through an ie-only stylesheet using conditional comments, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

The below code helps to create a tag shape. It works in all major browsers.

```css
#swc {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 5px 0 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 66px;
  padding: 0 35px 0 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 65px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin: 20px 25px;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  transition: background 0.3s;
}

#swc:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  right: -19px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 0px;
  border-left: 18px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-top: 33px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 33px solid transparent;
  transition: border 0.3s;
}

#swc:hover {
  background: green;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#swc:hover:after {
  border-left-color: green;
}
```

```html
<span class="pricetag-right" id="swc">Tag Content!</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

We had a slightly different implementation of this that produces rounded corners. This uses a rounded square that's turned 45°.

```css
.tag {
  display: inline-block;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #c8d7f2 transparent #c8d7f2 #c8d7f2;
  border-radius: .25em 0 0 .25em;
  padding: 0.1em 0.6em 0.1em 0.3em;
  background-color: #e5ecf9;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

.tag:after {
  content: "\25CF";
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1.2em;
  width: 1.17em;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  color: white;
  text-indent: 0.3em;
  line-height: 1em;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #333;
  background-color: #e5ecf9;
  border-radius: 0.33em 0.33em 0.33em 1em;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #c8d7f2 #c8d7f2 transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="tag">my-tag</h1>
```

A couple things to note:

1. The square contains a circle punctuation mark. To adjust it you use line-height and text-indent.
2. The borders on the square need to be set to transparent color with a width of 1px. If you don't, the other borders (the visible ones) taper off where they go from 1px to 0px.
3. his works pretty well and it's nearly pixel-perfect, but it does render slightly differently across Chrome and Firefox. I tried to make it work with a transparent background, but you need some sort of color to cover up the funkiness where the square meets the tag. It's not *quite* perfect.

The nice thing about this is that it can be applied as a class and it can be used on H1-H6, or p tags.