# How to make transparent arrow?

Tags: html, css, border, css-shapes

I have this issue, I can't figure out how I can make the the arrow transparent.

So basically I just use `:after` to make a `border` with these values to make an arrow. 
But what I would like is to make the arrow transparent so you could see the background image, which is a background image in the `header` tag.

The CSS:

```
html,body {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    font-family:'open-sans', sans-serif;
}
header {width:100%;}
main {
    width:100%;
    min-height:50vh;
    position:relative;
}
main:after {
    top:0;
    left:50%;
    border:solid transparent; 
    content:""; 
    height:0; 
    width:0; 
    position:absolute; 
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); 
    border-top-color:#2a2a2a; 
    border-width:60px; 
    margin-left: -60px;
}
```

The HTML:

```
    <header class="bg__header">
    </header>
    <main>
        <article></article>
    </main>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PR4DE/or80n4ob/)**

And here a golden example of what I want to achieve:

[image: transparent arrow]

Comment: are you looking for this?? http://jsfiddle.net/or80n4ob/1/

Comment: No sorry if i have explained it in a wrong way :) 
i want to have complete transparency down to the background image. 
so it would be like an arrow cut into the main div.

Comment: is it possible to add screenshot what you want to achieve, i mean your goal??

Comment: yea ofc. :) i will make something brilliant in photoshop x,D 
give me a min.

Comment: something like this :) 
http://imgur.com/MzUV8W8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done but will require some extra pseudo elements. You need to reverse your logic a little and make the arrow "cut out" the background as CSS arrows are achieved using `border`s and can't have background images.

- Make `.bg__header` `position: relative;` to ensure the pseudo elements are positioned relatively to it.
- Add `.bg__header:before` and `.bg__header:after`, these will provide the white borders left and right of the transparent arrow.
- Amend `main:after` to make the arrow transparent and the sides white.

You've got quite a bit of code in your fiddle so for simplicity sake these are the changes:

```
.bg__header {
    position: relative;
}
.bg__header:before {
    content:"";
    background-color: white;
    height: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 50%;
    left: -60px;
}
.bg__header:after {
    content:"";
    background-color: white;
    height: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 50%;
    right: -60px;
}
main:after {
    border-color: white;
    border-top-color: transparent;
    top: -60px;
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/2pjxfs4n/2/

Comment: excellent :D 
And thank you for the constructive answer, i learned alot.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in another way. First of all, you do not need the this one rule

> border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);

as it is not changing anything.

Inspite of using transparent option to your border present value of the border-top-color in rgba and use alpha chanel like this

> border-top-color:rgba(42,42,42,0.4);

hope this will work for you

Comment: Not exacly what i needed :) but ty anyway. i have updated the post with the example of what i need.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you want.had set some `width` and `height` to the `main:after` and had rotated it so that it looks like an arrow
Modified `main:after` like this

```
main:after {
    /*ARROW on header tag*/
    top:-50px;
    left:50%;
    height:60px;
    width:60px;
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    margin-left: -60px;

    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    border-bottom:solid 1px black;
     border-right:solid 1px black;
}
```

[CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/or80n4ob/2/)

Comment: Refer this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23758922/transparent-css-arrow-triangle-over-an-image

Comment: Interesting solution :) 
but still not quite what i need.
here is what i am looking for:
http://imgur.com/MzUV8W8

Comment: Oh i just saw what u refered, perfect! i will see if i can get it to work :)