# Implement a rectangle shape with a transparent triangular cut at bottom

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

I want to create a non-rectangular image with CSS3, I think implement something like below image [image]

It is a square with a **transparent** triangle gap in bottom of it, I know I can implement it with some trick, as example with png image but I want create this with HTML element not with image,
any body know how can I do that? Is that implementable with HTML and CSS?

Comment: Is that triangle transparent or white in color? Also, is there anything you tried first? because am tempted to close vote for not sharing your code

Comment: @Mr.Alien it is  transparent

Comment: Since you haven't put much efforts, all I can suggest you is to use css clip

Comment: @zhilevan add to your OP that you want the triangle to be transparent.

Comment: @zhilevan: Do you need to support older versions of IE?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transparent CSS arrow/triangle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23758922/transparent-css-arrow-triangle)

Comment: @web-tiki: True, overlapping two skewed pseudo's is also a very good option. I think skew would also produce a sharper output in all browsers. Only drawback (as usual) is IE older versions :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### <----------------------------------------------- `clip-path` solution ------------------------------------------------->

You could use `clip-path` to do this:

### [dabblet](http://dabblet.com/gist/adcc9bc6411a1ee4aa8e)

```
.rect {
    position: absolute;
    width: 165px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 40% 100%, 50% 75%, 60% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
}

body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

**Note:** Firefox does not support this property.

Works fine on Chrome.

**Check out the browser support for `clip-path` ----------> [HERE](http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path)**.

---

### <------------------------- `<svg>` solution - will support all browsers [except IE8] ------------------------->

Since, Firefox still supports `clip-path: url()`, you can create an inline `svg` element with a `polygon` element inside `clipPath` that defines the `points`. Give the `clipPath` element an `id`(`#mask`) and use it in CSS instead of `polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 40% 100%, 50% 75%, 60% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);`.

### [dabblet](http://dabblet.com/gist/4f88471e6453abae10ca)

#### HTML:

```
<div class="rect"></div>
<svg>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="mask">
      <polygon points="0,0 0,100 66,100 82.5,75 99,100 165,100 165,0 " />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

#### CSS:

```
.rect {
    position: absolute;
    width: 165px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-clip-path: url(#mask);
    clip-path: url(#mask);
}
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

---

### <---------------------------------------- `<svg>` solution without any CSS ---------------------------------------->

### [dabblet](http://dabblet.com/gist/d7553de9591407c541a7)

#### HTML:

```
<svg>
    <polygon points="0,0 0,100 66,100 82.5,75 99,100 165,100 165,0" style="fill:black" />
</svg>
```

**Check out browsers that supports `svg` ----------> [HERE](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg)**

Comment: Thanks for your attetion,I test in chorme work correcty, but I need also firefox, do you have another solution? can we implement it with polygon or something like it?

Comment: @zhilevan - Working on it as we speak.

Comment: @zhilevan - Check out my updated answer, now it will support all browsers.

Comment: +1. I would say SVG is a better option given it has IE9 support (which linear-gradients don't have). However, I don't think SVG is supported in IE8. You may want to indicate that.

Comment: but if I want use svg it think this is simple solution 
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg height="500" width="700">
  <polygon points="100,10 100,300 300,300 350,250 400,300 600,300 600,10 " style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:1" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>

</body>
</html>
` :(.

Answer (score 2):

**A simple approach**

Use `box-shadow` on pseudoelement, and use `overflow: hidden;` on main element.

```css
div {
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div:before{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 67px;
    content: "";
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: transparent;
    transform-origin:0% 100%;
    transform: rotate(52deg) skewX(10deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(52deg) skewX(10deg);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 200px black;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to produce this transparent cut at the bottom is to use a couple of skewed pseudo-elements and position them such that they leave a triangle shaped gap at the bottom. Below is a sample snippet demonstrating this approach.

```css
body {
  background: url("http://lorempixel.com/200/400");
}
.shape {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.shape:before {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background: black;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-30deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-30deg);
  transform: skew(-30deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 25% -25%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 25% -25%;
  transform-origin: 25% -25%;
}
.shape:after {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background: black;
  -webkit-transform: skew(30deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(30deg);
  transform: skew(30deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 25% -25%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 25% -25%;
  transform-origin: 25% -25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

---

> **Note:** This below snippet is only to show that achieving a shape with transparent cut is possible by using overlapping gradient backgrounds. However, my advice would be to not use this approach as much as possible because gradients produce jagged corners a lot of the times.

You can use two overlapping linear-gradient backgrounds on a `div` to achieve this effect. The angles of the triangle can be modified by modifying the gradient's angles. This is tested and found to be working fine in Mozilla FireFox, Chrome, Safari and Opera.

```css
body {
  background: url("http://lorempixel.com/200/400");
}
.shape {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-10deg, black 50%, transparent 50%), -webkit-linear-gradient(10deg, transparent 50%, black 50%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-10deg, black 50%, transparent 50%), -moz-linear-gradient(10deg, transparent 50%, black 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(100deg, black 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(-100deg, black 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

One potential drawback of this approach is that the edges aren't really sharp in Chrome (atleast in older versions of Chrome) whereas it is sharp in the others.