# Border with a transparent centred arrow

Tags: html, css, border, css-shapes

I am trying to style a div with a **bottom-border that has a downward-pointing arrow**. The div will have an image in it, and should not have a top, right or left border. The fill of the downward-pointing arrow should be either the same as the div or transparent.

I have been able to get it to work for the most part using the code below:

```css
.hero {
  position: relative;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 320px !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
.hero:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: solid 50px #e15915;
  border-left: solid 50px transparent;
  border-right: solid 50px transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero"></div>
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alisamii/tjep3h8t/

Whatever I try to do to "hollow-out" the arrow either results in a borderless div (so it has a fill of yellow but no border on any side) or in a border that goes around the whole div.

Any help?

Comment: This should help : [transparent arrow/triangle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23758922/transparent-arrow-triangle/23759602#23759602)

Comment: _"The fill of the downward-pointing arrow should be either the same as the div or transparent."_ , If the arrow is transparent, what is the point of having it?

Comment: The border-bottom isn't transparent. The idea is to create this display, which is done using an image: http://d.pr/i/1bT5J As you can see, there is a 1px line with a downward-pointing arrow. So, I want to create the div that has the border-bottom and no border-left, border-right or border-top.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two methods to achieve this using CSS3. One is using `skewX` on pseudo-elements while the other is using `rotate` on pseudo-elements. Both the methods are **also responsive**.

### Using Skew:

This method is adapted from **web-tiki's** answer in [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23758922/transparent-arrow-triangle/23759602#23759602) thread. It basically uses two pseudo-elements (with roughly 50% width of the container) that are skewed in opposite directions and positioned appropriately to arrive at the arrow shape. The shapes have borders where as the `background` is set to transparent meaning the pseudo-elements would produce a bottom border + downward arrow effect. The arrow fill would always be transparent (or body color) in this sample.

```css
body {
  background: rgb(245, 242, 242);
}
.bordered {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  line-height: 200px;
}
.bordered:after,
.bordered:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: ' ';
  height: 8px;
  width: 50%;
  bottom: 0px;
}
.bordered:before {
  left: 0px;
  border-top: 1px solid gray;
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: skewX(45deg);
}
.bordered:after {
  right: 0px;
  border-top: 1px solid gray;
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
  transform-origin: right bottom;
  transform: skewX(-45deg);
}
.bordered img {
  width: 150px;
  padding: 25px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
/* Just for demo */

.bordered {
  transition: all 1s;
  text-align: center;
}
.bordered:hover {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  line-height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<!-- library included only to avoid browser prefixes -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

<div class="bordered">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/0Xqum3A.png" />
</div>
```

[image]

The below method would produce a transparent triangle such that the **page's background is seen through the triangular cut**.

```css
body {
  background: rgb(245, 242, 242);
}
.bordered {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  background-clip: content-box;
  line-height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.bordered.top {
  padding-top: 8px;
}
.bordered.bottom {
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}
.bordered:after,
.bordered:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: ' ';
  height: 8px;
  width: 50%;
  background: inherit;
}
.bordered.top:after,
.bordered.top:before {
  top: 0px;
}
.bordered.bottom:after,
.bordered.bottom:before {
  bottom: 0px;
}
.bordered:before {
  left: 0px;
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
}
.bordered.top:before {
  border-top: 1px solid gray;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: skewX(45deg);
}
.bordered.bottom:before {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform: skewX(-45deg);
}
.bordered:after {
  right: 0px;
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
}
.bordered.top:after {
  border-top: 1px solid gray;
  transform-origin: right bottom;
  transform: skewX(-45deg);
}
.bordered.bottom:after {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  transform-origin: right top;
  transform: skewX(45deg);
}
.bordered img {
  width: 150px;
  padding: 25px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/* Just for demo */

div{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class="bordered top">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/0Xqum3A.png" />
</div>

<div class="bordered bottom">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/0Xqum3A.png" />
</div>
```

---

### Using Rotate:

This method uses a rotated pseudo-element (rotated by 45 degrees) to achieve the downward arrow effect and is then placed on top of the bottom `border` of the `div`. In this method, the `background` of the pseudo-element is set to the same color as the `div` containing it. (**Note:** In this sample the image and `div` have different fill colors.)

```css
body {
  background: lightgray;
}
.colored {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  line-height: 200px;
}
.colored img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 25px;
}
.colored {
  background: yellow;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
.colored:after {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-top-width: 0px;
  border-left-width: 0px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  bottom: -6px;
  left: calc(50% - 4px);
}

/* Just for demo */

.colored{
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.colored:hover{
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  line-height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<!-- library included only to avoid prefixes -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

<div class="colored">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/0Xqum3A.png" />
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer. Thank you. It provides me with two options, both of which have flexibility and the ability to provide a more accurate and creative solution.

Comment: Unrealted, but you seem to have a strong grasp of edge-layout capabilities (not that the above is very "edge, but what the heck). Maybe you could look at this other question I posted about using flexbox with twbs3 and provide some insight there? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27743257/using-flexbox-with-bootstrap-3-and-laravel-4-blade-templates-and-associated-less

Comment: @alisamii: Was just reading that question mate. Pure CSS and Less I would have definitely tried. Laravel and Bootstrap, I am not really that comfortable as I have never used Laravel and very rarely used bootstrap. But let me give it a try :)

Answer (score 5):

A simple solution where the background of the arrow will be transparent, allowing you to use it on changing backgrounds:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="line-separator">
    <div class="side-line"> </div>
    <div class="triangle"> </div>
    <div class="side-line"> </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.side-line {
    display: inline-block;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    width: 20%;
}

.triangle {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 7px;
    width: 7px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin: center center;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0 -3px -3px;
}
```

**Live demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/85saaphw/

Comment: I wish I could give you more than one upvote!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the best solution, but one option could be to use a `:before` to render the orange triangle and a `:after` to render a slightly smaller triangle with the color of your background. The `:after` triangle mostly covers the `:before` triangle leaving only a small orange triangle border. Unfortunately it can't be transparent if you solve it in this way.

```css
.hero {
  position: relative;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 320px !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
.hero:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: solid 50px #e15915;
  border-left: solid 50px transparent;
  border-right: solid 50px transparent;
}
.hero:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -48px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: solid 48px yellow;
  border-left: solid 48px transparent;
  border-right: solid 48px transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero"></div>
```