# Triangle upside down with rounded corner

Tags: html, css

I need to recreate an effect like this one in the header of my website.
I would like to do it via CSS, anyone can help me cause I'm stuck with that triangle...

Here is my test:

```css
#main-nav {height:200px;width:1200px;background-color:#000}
#triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 300px 300px 0px 0px;
    border-color: #007bff transparent transparent transparent;
    border-radius: 70px 2px 2px 2px;
    margin: auto;
    top: -400px;
    position: relative;
    /* background-color: #ccc; */
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
    /* border-top: 80px solid blue; */
    /* border-bottom: 80px solid blue; */
    /* border-right:80px solid blue; */
}
```

```html
<div id="main-nav">
</div>
<div id="triangle">
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: These would help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27462276/border-with-a-transparent-or-same-color-centred-arrow-on-a-div or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23758922/transparent-arrow-triangle/23759602#23759602

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

**CSS**

```
#main-nav {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 1200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #D1C5B9;
  z-index: 1;
}

#triangle {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: #3C3C3A;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 4;
}

#triangle:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  transform: rotate(15deg);
  background: #3C3C3A;
  z-index: 4;
  border-radius: 14px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -65px;
  top: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #3C3C3A;
}

#triangle:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  transform: rotate(-15deg);
  background: #3C3C3A;
  z-index: 3;
  border-radius: 14px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: 0;
  top: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #3C3C3A;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="main-nav">
  <div id="triangle">
  </div>
</div>
```

**NOTE:** Adjust as your needs

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/85/)**