# DIV cut by a triangle in CSS

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to achieve something like this in CSS and how?
Many thanks,

[image]

Comment: This also would help (it has borders) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27462276/border-with-a-transparent-centred-arrow

Comment: Thanks! It does hep!