# Left/right transparent cut out arrow

Tags: css, svg, css-shapes

I am aware this has been answered previously however that was for the bottom of a div and I cannot work out how to do it for the left and right of a div.

I am trying to acheive the same effect as this:

```css
BODY {
  background: url(http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5506/9699081016_ba090f1238_h.jpg) 0 -100px;
}
#wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 116px;
}
#test {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  position: relative;
}
#test:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -6px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 16px;
  top: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-40deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-40deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-40deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-40deg);
  transform: skew(-40deg);
}
#test:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -6px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 16px;
  top: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transform: skew(40deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(40deg);
  -o-transform: skew(40deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(40deg);
  transform: skew(40deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="test"></div>
</div>
```

But with the cut out on the **left** and another with the cut out on the **right**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution is adapted from this answer : [Transparent arrow/triangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23758922/transparent-arrow-triangle/23759602#23759602)

The point is to use two skewed pseudo elements to make the transparent cut out arrow. Both pseudo elements are absolutely positioned and skewed.

In the following demo, the arrow is on the left. To make the same on on the right, you could duplicate the `.arrow` element and use `scaleX(-1)` + positioning on the second one. This will allow you to change both sides at the same time and have less *CSS*. Or you can make a new element based on the first one and change the positioning and skew properties.

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/BydMYX)**

[image: Left cut out arrow]

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.wrap img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top:0;
  width: 3%;
  height:100%;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
}
.arrow:before, .arrow:after {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height:50%;
  background-color: inherit;
}
.arrow:before {
  bottom: 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -ms-transform: skewY(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-45deg);
  transform: skewY(-45deg);
}
.arrow:after {
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  -ms-transform: skewY(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewY(45deg);
  transform: skewY(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6217/6216951796_e50778255c.jpg" />
    <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

---

For the same output, you can use an [svg](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/SVG) :

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/BydMEN?editors=110)**

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.wrap img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
.arrow{
  position:absolute;
  left:0; top:0;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6217/6216951796_e50778255c.jpg" />
  <svg class="arrow" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 10 100">
    <path d="M-1 -1 H10 V45 L5 50 L10 55 V101 H-1z" fill="#fff" fill-opacity="0.8" stroke-width="0"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer! I will try this out and if I can get it to work will mark as answered!

Comment: Worked brilliantly! Thank you

Answer (score 4):

It can be made with a single element using inset `box-shadow` and pseudo-elements `:before` and `:after`

The elements are skewed by **45deg** and **-45deg** to create the transparent gap. Inset box-shadow is used to increase the width of the arrow banner.

**[Fiddle (1 element)](http://jsfiddle.net/Lre2fakb/)**

```css
body {
  font-size: 10px;
}
div {
  background: url('https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6217/6216951796_e50778255c.jpg');
  height: 33.3em;
  width: 50em;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: inset 2em 0 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
div:before, div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 2em;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  height: 25em;
  width: 2em;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
div:before {
  bottom: -8.35em;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(45deg);
  -moz-transform: skewY(45deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(45deg);
  transform: skewY(45deg);
}
div:after {
  top: -8.35em;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: skewY(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(-45deg);
  transform: skewY(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**Bugs :** Browser rendering of `box-shadow` isn't consistent when using veiwport units. On zooming-out to 33%, GC shows 1px gap b/w pseudo-element and box-shadow. This bug doesn't occur with `px` and `em` units on zooming.

---

A better approach than the one given above would be to use one element on top of `img` element. The rest properties (`overflow: hidden;`, `box-shadow`) too are used, but this doesn't have the gap between the arrow even on zooming.

**[Fiddle (2 elements)](http://jsfiddle.net/okpychbx/)**

[image]

---

**Note :**

- Ideas used from earlier post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28515844/2511146).
- All measurements are done in `em` with a set font-size of 10px.

Answer (score 3):

You could use CSS3's `clip-path` property but it's a bit [bleeding-edge](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path). However, if you don't need to support IE there are plenty of useful examples at http://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

```css
div {background: yellow; width:400px; height:300px;}
div img {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(10% 0%, 90% 0%, 90% 100%, 90% 40%, 100% 50%, 90% 60%, 90% 100%, 10% 100%, 10% 60%, 0% 50%, 10% 40%);  
    clip-path: polygon(10% 0%, 90% 0%, 90% 100%, 90% 40%, 100% 50%, 90% 60%, 90% 100%, 10% 100%, 10% 60%, 0% 50%, 10% 40%);
}
```

```html
<div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/nature/" /></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hey I just modified your existing one. Probably could have done it a bit cleaner but you get the idea. This is the left side. Pretty easy to swap it to the right from this.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2hCrw/303/)

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="test"><div id="fill"></div>
<div id="fill2"></div></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
BODY{
background: url(http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5506/9699081016_ba090f1238_h.jpg) 0 -100px;}

#wrapper {
overflow: hidden;
height: 116px;}

#fill{
height: 40px;
position:absolute;
width:30px;
left:-30px;
background: #ccc;}

#fill2{
height: 40px;
position:absolute;
width:30px;
background: #ccc;
bottom:0;
left:-30px;}

#test {
height: 116px;
width: 692px;
background-color: #ccc;
position: relative;
float:right;}

#test:before {
content:"";
position: absolute;
top: 40px;
height: 50%;
width: 30px;
left: 0;
background-color: #ccc;
-webkit-transform: skew(40deg);
-moz-transform: skew(40deg);
-o-transform: skew(40deg);
-ms-transform: skew(40deg);
transform: skew(40deg);}

#test:after {
content:"";
position: absolute;
bottom: 40px;
height: 50%;
width: 30px;
left: 0;
background-color: #ccc;
-webkit-transform: skew(-40deg);
-moz-transform: skew(-40deg);
-o-transform: skew(-40deg);
-ms-transform: skew(-40deg);
transform: skew(-40deg);}
```