# How to make a CSS3 Clip Path

Tags: css, svg, clip-path

I want to make figure 1

[image]

like as figure 2

[image]

using clip path, is it possible?

thanks.

Comment: Have a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23758922/transparent-arrow-triangle/23759602#23759602. The output produced is similar to what you need even though it doesn't use clip-path. Unless you are planning to use SVG clip-path, I would recommend the approach described in the linked thread because CSS only clip-path has very low browser support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clip-path` is still a very experimental CSS3 element and therefore isn't very well supported and what support there is is minimal.

Using the CSS3 `clip-path` element to generate the polygon only allows for straight corners as its all point based rather than allowing for curves.

Heres an example:

```css
body {
  background: #555;
  margin: 0;
}
img {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(98% 0, 100% 2%, 100% 88%, 98% 90%, 25% 90%, 20% 99%, 15% 90%, 2% 90%, 0 88%, 0 2%, 2% 0);
  clip-path: polygon(98% 0, 100% 2%, 100% 88%, 98% 90%, 25% 90%, 20% 99%, 15% 90%, 3% 90%, 0 88%, 0 2%, 2% 0);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" />
```

Your best alternative would be to use an actual SVG element and reference it within the CSS to do the cut out. If you want a perfect shape but sadly no support on IE, this is the way to go.

[SVG Only Version](http://codepen.io/stewartside/pen/OyMQyv)

```css
body {
  background: #555;
  margin: 0;
}
img {
  clip-path: url(#svgPath);
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#svgPath);
}
```

```html
<svg height="0" width="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="svgPath">
      <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M50,0 L450,0 Q500,0 500,50 L500,400 Q500,450 450,450 L200,450 L175,500 L150,450 L50,450 Q0,450 0,400 L0,50 Q0,0 50,0z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>

<img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/" />
```