# Image with bottom triangle that overlay another image

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

It is simple to create arrow [at the bottom of image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23758922/transparent-arrow-triangle).

But is this possible to achive something like this where second image is not background but another image that goes after first image:
[image: Image with triangle at the bottom over image]

I created "pen" on [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/Nicolai8/pen/VvpOKB?editors=110)

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 70%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.wrap img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.arrow:before,
.arrow:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.arrow:before {
  right: 50%;
  border-bottom: 20px solid #000;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
}
.arrow:after {
  left: 50%;
  border-bottom: 20px solid #000;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7187/6895047173_d4b1a0d798.jpg" />
  <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/EinPKO3.jpg" />
  <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23758922/transparent-arrow-triangle?lq=1), However if you want to overlap .. you can use negative margins.

Comment: Try using Stack Snippets instead of sites such as codepen.io.

Comment: @ImranBughio, example from link you posted asnwers on question with parent>child relation but I ask about siblings elements

Comment: Good question! I add to my favourites with the star to make me update about this topic. Good luck because it's a real interesting problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the answer you linked to there are 2 approaches that allow the output you are looking for.

If you look under the 4th approach (Tooltip with a triangle over an image.) the technique shown is the same as what facebook uses for tooltips when you hover a name.

[image: Tooltip with triangle over non plain content]

Although this approach has a better browser support, I would prefer to use an svg approach (also provided in the post you linked to) with the `clipPath` element to make the triangle at the bottom.

Adapted to your use case, it could look like this :

```css
*{margin:0;}
svg{
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  margin-bottom:-3.5%;
  z-index:50;
}
svg:nth-child(2){
  z-index:49;
}
svg:nth-child(3){
  z-index:48;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 600 400">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip">
      <path d="M0 0 H600 V380 H320 L300 400 L280 380 H0z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/people/1" width="600" height="400" clip-path="url(#clip)"/>
</svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 600 400">
  <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/nature/1" width="600" height="400" clip-path="url(#clip)"/>
</svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 600 400">
  <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/abstract/6" width="600" height="400" clip-path="url(#clip)"/>
</svg>
```

Note that for simplicity the demo uses images with the same aspect ratio. Each image is in its own svg tag for maintainability (example: add or remove an image)

Output :

[image: Image with bottom triangle over another image]

More info on MDN :

- [clipPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath)
- [svg](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg)

Comment: great job dude working in FireFox and Internet Explorer as well

Comment: @web-tiki, looks good, but I have one more question: how can I put content over images (the idea is that image will be a background for content): each image has its own content... Sure, with JS I can get size of content I need to place and size of svg and then with absolute positioning place content over images...but is there best solution?

Comment: looks better, but anyway when I resize the page image resizes too

Answer (score 6):

hi i haven't show you code deeply but as per your desired out put image

i have created following in my way and here it is the code of that

> **Please Note** : This will not work with the Internet Explorer and
>   FireFox
>
> **In FireFox clip-path support by the only url value**
>
> for browser support please look at following reference link
>
> **[Browser Support for clip-path](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path)**

```css
.boundry{   
    margin-top:100px;
    margin-left:100px;
    width:50%;
    margin-bottom:100px;    
}
.arrow_box {
    height:180px;
 position: relative;
 background: #88b7d5;   
    padding:15px;     
    text-align:center;    
    color:white;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 80%, 46% 80%, 51% 90%, 56% 80%, 0% 80%);
    clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 80%, 46% 80%, 51% 90%, 56% 80%, 0% 80%);
}
.arrow_box:nth-child(1){         
    background:url('http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-lz3nDbV440A/VO4QpcN4ZCI/AAAAAAAAN94/PAYUtUysb-4/s1600/happy-holi-images-2015%2B(9).jpg');  
    color:grey;
    z-index: 5;
}
.arrow_box:nth-child(2){
    margin-top: -42px;
    margin-bottom: -35px;      
    background:url('http://blog.jimdo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/tree-247122.jpg');
}
```

```html
<div class="boundry" >
    <div class="arrow_box">
       <h1 class="logo">first image</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="arrow_box">
       <h1 class="logo">second image</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the working demo code for this

**[Demo Code](https://jsfiddle.net/7tfs9v4s/3/)**

Comment: @Nicolai please look at my answer

Comment: @Nicolai let me check

Comment: @Nicolai in IE and FireFox this clip-path is not suported dude sorry for that but Chrome fully supports this

Comment: @Nicolai even couldn't find any alternatives, i will include as i found any other way

Answer (score -1):

If you want to stack images you have many different methods to use. You can always use the z-index to put them in different orders. You can use .png files to add contrast to the layout.

Comment: the problem is **how** to use z-index to achive what I need...and I can't use proper .png image that already has arrow at the bottom.

Comment: Use `z-index` with `nth-child` to target wrap class like this: `.wrap:nth-child(1){ z-index: 2; }`