# How to design pointed tab in css? How is that triangle getting created?

Tags: css, css-shapes

I want to design a pointed tab in my web page, like the one below

(it is in espncricinfo.com)

Another user has referred me the link, 
[Transparent arrow/triangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23758922/transparent-arrow-triangle)

But I couldnt understand , how that triangle is exactly getting created? Which code is actually creating it?

[image]

I want to do it by own in css. I don't want to make use of bootstrap or semantic css, which are readily available. Kindly let me know the trick to design this segment.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Closed as a dupe (even though the linked question is about transparent arrow on top of an image) because the same approach can be used here also.

Comment: @ketan Yes i tried. But I couldnt understand where is the exact code line in the link referenced (in the question below), that creates triangle.